# Ethernet acting weird, stops working after few minutes

Tags: dual-boot, internet, ethernet, 22.04, wired

I have a dual boot system, Windows 11 with Ubuntu 22.04. Internet on Windows with wireless and wire both works perfectly without any interruption or any issue. On Ubuntu wireless works perfectly but the wired internet acts weird.

Here are some scenarios :

1. When booted directly into ubuntu, the ethernet will work for a few minutes, maybe a maximum of 30 minutes and then it will stop working. Now if I try to unplug the LAN cable and replug it in my laptop, my laptop is stuck at connecting, and it won't get the IP address. Even restarting the ubuntu won't solve this. To make the ethernet work again, I have to boot into windows and then again boot back into ubuntu and the ethernet starts working.
2. Booting first into windows and then booting back to Ubuntu, the ethernet works perfectly without any issue.

This wasn't the issue before. A software updater window popped up on ubuntu as usual and I updated it as always. But this time after the update, the issue with the ethernet started.

I tried searching on the internet but couldn't solve the problem, I am not very experienced with Ubunut.

`lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38df]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 updated the question

Comment: Install `r8168-dkms` and test if it works better. And is Fast Startup disabled in Windows. First to disable it then try the above solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that Windows Fast Startup feature is disabled and try again.

If that doesn't help, disable Secure Boot and install the vendor driver by

```
sudo apt install r8168-dkms
```

Comment: The fast startup was disabled from the beginning. After Installing r8168-dkms and testing for a few hours, no issues were faced. I think it solved the problem, Thank you.

Comment: For more context on why to disable Fast Startup: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled